# Postgresql, writing views

Tags: database, postgresql, view

I am not strong in DB knowledge, especially Postgresql. So the istuation is: I have two columns in a table num_bigger and num_lower. I need to make a third column that is

`elapsed = num_bigger - num lower`

I've googled it and figured out that the best way to do this is to make a view(Also I found how to do this using triggers, but they are not allowed for me). Any suggestions how to make this kind of view ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use that expression in a SELECT statement:

```
select num_bigger, 
       num_lower,
       num_bigger - num_lower as elapsed
from the_table;
```

If you want to make a view out of it, then use:

```
create view some_view_name
as
select ....;
```

More details in the manual:

- [assigning an alias to an expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS)
- [create view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html)
- [expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html)